# Insert/update Firestore document export in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, insert-update

I have a Firestore docuement like as like below and it is exported to Storage
[image]

Then, I have created a table for the document in Google BigQuery.

[image]

I have tried to write an update/insert query.

`` UPDATE `dataset.feed` set d_1.0 = "Imagelink" ``

also, tried to use UNNEST to breakdown the array by following the Firestore documentation. Still, I can't figure out how to write an update/insert for a document.

Answer (score 0):

Array can only be updated as a whole:

```
UPDATE `dataset.feed` SET d_1 = ["t0", "t1"] WHERE ...
```